# Copy the selected row in Grid view

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Using VB.Net

User Enter the values in GridView columns

Each Row having the checkbox, User want to copy the one row to another row if checkbox is selected.

For Example

user entered the values in first 2 row, again user don't want to enter the values, user want to copy the first 2 row to next 2 rows.

```
If gridview1.column(0).checkbox1.checked = True then
'Copy that selected row to next row. (Here i have to create a table to copy the new rows or i can copy directly gridrow values without creating a tables)
```

Gridview1

Checkbox ID Name

```
check/uncheck 001 Raja
check/uncheck 002 Ramu
check/uncheck 003 Vijay
.....
```

If i check the last 2 row means it should add automatically, ID Number also should increase

Expected Ouput

```
check/uncheck 001 Raja
check/uncheck 002 Ramu
check/uncheck 003 Vijay
check/uncheck 004 Ramu
check/uncheck 005 Vijay
.....
```

How to do this.  Give me a ideas

Need VB.Net Code Help

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Figuring out which rows need to be copied or how to perform the copy or both?

Comment: @ConradFrix, I posted one example, now you can go through....

Comment: This reminds me of this other question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750746/how-to-copy-one-row-to-another-row-in-gridview/7753265#7753265

Also asked by you.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer from your previous version of this question.  Which should work.  I added code to increase the id number of an added row.

```
      For Each m_row As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow In Me.grvLIst.Rows
        'Create new row to hold duplicated values
        Dim NewRow As New DataGridViewRow
        'make row have same columns as other rows in the datagrid
        NewRow.CreateCells(Me.grvLIst)
        'loop thru values in the row being copied and place values in new row
        For i As Integer = 0 To m_row.Cells.Count - 1
            NewRow.Cells(i).Value = m_row.Cells(i).Value
        Next

        'This will increase the id number by 1 based on the last rows id number
        NewRow.Cells(1).Value = Me.grvLIst.Rows(Me.grvLIst.RowCount - 1).Cells(1).Value + 1
        'Add newly create row to gridview

        Me.grvLIst.Rows.Add(NewRow)

    Next
```

Comment: It's adding the empty column, with number 1.  I want to add the column with previous row data's...

Comment: Cloning the row should provide an exact duplicate... but if you prefer you can copy the values individually. Editing answer for that method.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, It is showing error as "Specified cast is not valid." on this line "For Each cell As DataGridCell In m_row.Cells".  Can you please check....

Comment: not working at all, can you check ur code again, please.  When i selected the checkbox and clicked, nothing happening....

Comment: The loop works for copying selected rows.  I tested each answer I posted.  If its not working when you check it use debug to make sure its even hitting the loop at all.