# Copy and Paste Selected Rows in an unbound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I've tried changing the ClipboardCopyMode to "EnableWithoutHeaderText" in the DataGridView properties but this did not work. Also, I tried doing this programmatically with the code below, but it did not work either. Please help.

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    Me.DataGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure this can help you or not Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750746/how-to-copy-one-row-to-another-row-in-gridview

Comment: Any improvement ? Just to make sure i'm not wasting time :)

Comment: What's the requirement exactly? Please add a description about what do you want to do, what do you expect and tell us what's the problem by the code which you tried.

Comment: @KitkatFang this is not what I'm looking for. I want the ability to copy and paste rows wherever.

Comment: @noidea no progress has been made on this.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I would like to be able to cut and paste rows like you would be able to in excel.

Comment: Does your `DataGridView` is bound to a `DataTable` or something?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Nope, Im importing the data in through a file browser dialog

Comment: So the most simple Option is loading the data first into a `DataTable` and the use the `DataTable` as `DataSource` of `DataGridView`. Then you can simply copy the data of some rows of the `DataTable` and add them into the `DataTable` itself. Then the pasted rows will be shown immediately in `DataGrridView`. Also as another option you can copy data of selected rows of `DataGridView` into an array/list and add them to the grid again. I'll post an answer based on the second option after I got access my laptop :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks! I am going to try this myself while I await you to post some code.

Comment: If you need the feature also using a data-bound DataGridView, ask a new question about it. Also I noticed you've just accepted a single answer. JFYI, whan a post answers your quetsion it would be great if you accept and upvote it. To accept click chekc mark near the answer and to upvote click up arrow near the answer.

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about this post :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei So, I don't think I've explained myself properly. I would like the user to be able to cut and paste rows once they've imported the data. Let me know if I need to further explain myself. I appreciate your help.

Comment: This post is specific to copy selected rows of `DataGridView` and pasting them in specified index. For example I pasted the to index 0 by setting `insertAt = 0`. If you need a different index, just use another index. Also you said *I would like to be able to cut and paste rows like you would be able to in excel*. If you need to cut them, simply delete `SelectedRows` after pasting those cloned rows.

Comment: By the way, this post about copy/paste selected rows of data grid view, seems answer your question. Let me know if you have any question about it or if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone selected rows with values of cells, then you can use [`InsertRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insertrange(v=vs.110).aspx) to insert copies cells. Pay attention this way will work for an unbound `DataGridView` and if your `DataGridView` is bound, then you should copy records of the `DataSource` of control.

**C#**

```cs
var insertAt = 0;
var rows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                        .OrderBy(r=>r.Index)
                        .Select(r=>{
                            var clone = r.Clone() as DataGridViewRow;
                            for (int i = 0; i < r.Cells.Count; i++)
                                clone.Cells[i].Value= r.Cells[i].Value;
                            return clone;
                        }).ToArray();
dataGridView1.Rows.InsertRange(insertAt, rows);
```

**VB**

```vb
Dim insertAt = 0
Dim rows = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow) _
                        .OrderBy(Function(r) r.Index) _
                        .Select(Function(r)
                                    Dim clone = DirectCast(r.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
                                    For i = 0 To r.Cells.Count - 1
                                        clone.Cells(i).Value = r.Cells(i).Value
                                    Next
                                    Return clone
                                End Function) _
                        .ToArray()
DataGridView1.Rows.InsertRange(insertAt, rows)
```

**Note**

- `DataGridView.Rows` collection also have [`InsertCopies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.insertcopies(v=vs.110).aspx) method. But the method can only copy a contiguous range of rows. While above code can copy a non-contiguous selection as well.
- I used `OrderBy(r=>r.Index)` to insert rows in the same order which you see in grid not with order of selecting them.
- [`DataGridViewRow.Clone`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone.aspx) method clones a row with all its properties but not with cell values, so I copied values using the for loop.
- You can simply create an extension method based on above code. It would be more reusable.